# How to save child entity with shared primary key

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

#### The Problem

I have two entities, `Parent` & `Child`, I want them to share a primary key but I want the relationship to be uni-directional. Only the child should know about the parent. Is this possible with spring-data-jpa repositories?

#### What I've tried

- I've tried using the EntityManager directly and it works. I am able to first persist the `Parent` and then persist the `Child` entity. However, when I attempt the same using Spring's `JpaRepository` I get the following error: `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property`.
- I've tried modeling the `Child` entity differently with its own SERIAL id and a foreign key reference to the parent. This works but I'd prefer to use a shared primary key.

#### Parent entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "code")
  String code;

}
```

#### Child entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Child {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "code")
  String code;

  @MapsId
  @JoinColumn(name = "code")
  @OneToOne
  Parent parent;
}
```

#### Test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Slf4j
public class MapsByIdTest {

  @Autowired
  ChildRepository childRepo;

  @Autowired
  ParentRepo parentRepo;

  @Autowired
  EntityManager entityManager;

  @Test // FAILS with org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException
  public void testSpringDataJpaRepository() {

    Parent pA = parentRepo.save(Parent.builder().code("A").build());

    Child child = Child.builder().parent(pA).code("A").build();

    childRepo.save(child);
  }

  @Test // WORKS!
  public void testEntityManager() {

    Parent p = Parent.builder().code("A").build();
    entityManager.persist(p);

    Child child = Child.builder().code("A").parent(p).build();
    entityManager.persist(child);

    log.info(entityManager.find(Parent.class, "A").toString());
    log.info(entityManager.find(Child.class, "A").toString());

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will work fine:

```
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "code", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    String code;

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "code")
    @OneToOne
    Parent parent;
}
```

and test

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testSpringDataJpaRepository() {
    Parent pA = parentRepo.save(Parent.builder().code("A").build());
    Child child = Child.builder().parent(pA).build();
    childRepo.save(child);
}
```

To explain:
Look at the implementation of `SimpleJpaRepository.save`

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Than check `AbstractEntityInformation.isNew`.
It concludes that the entity is new only if its it is null (or 0 for numerical types).
Therefore, your `childRepo.save(child);` is equivalent to `entityManager.merge(child);`
Check that if you call merge in your second test,the error you receive is identical.

To solve the issue:

- don't set value on your child `@Id` (probably you want to force lombok not to generate setter for it as well). This will cause `persist` to be alled instead of `merge`
- notice that you have 2 fields `code` and `parent` mapped to the same db column. To make the mapping correct, I used forced `insertable = false, updatable = false` on the `@Id` column (the change of `parent` field will cause the correct sql to be generated)